# How to run a SQL script via BigQueryInsertJobOperator in DAG?

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am looking for a solution to run a sql script via the BigQueryInsertJobOperator operator.
There are very few examples to be found online for that and the ones I tried have failed so far.
Mainly I am getting **jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound**: error.

I have the following folder where I would like to save all my SQL scripts:

**my_bucket/dags/my_other_folder/sql_scripts**

I have used the **template_searchpath** attribute in the DAG's configuration:

```
with DAG(
        'DE_test',
        schedule_interval=None,
        default_args=default_dag_args,
        catchup=False,
        template_searchpath='/home/airflow/dags'
        ) as dag:
```

and I have specified the filename in the BigQueryInsertJobOperator:

```
Transform = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
        task_id='insert_data',
        configuration={
        'query': {
            'query': "{% include 'my_other_folder/test.sql' %}",
            'useLegacySql': False
                }
        },
        location='EU',
        )
```

No matter what I do I keep getting jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: my_other_folder/test.sql error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I have finally managed to find the answer, the problem was with the value set to the **template_searchpath** attribute of the DAG.

It should be

`template_searchpath='/home/airflow/gcs/dags/my_other_folder'`

or just

`template_searchpath='/home/airflow/gcs/dags'`

**instead of**

`template_searchpath='/home/airflow/dags/my_other_folder'`

Basically, it was missing the **/gcs/** sub folder in the path of the folder.
Now, I am still not sure as to why that is. Initially I thought that the path to the folder with SQL scripts would have to reflect the path to the folder in the GCP bucket which does not contain the **/gcs/** sub folder.

If anybody could educate me as to why it is different and why it needs the **/gcs/** sub folder I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```py
with DAG(
    'DE_test',
    schedule_interval=None,
    default_args=default_dag_args,
    catchup=False,
    template_searchpath='/home/airflow/dags/my_other_folder' # you can provide a list of paths
) as dag:
    Transform = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
        task_id='insert_data',
        configuration={
        'query': {
            'query': "{% include 'test.sql' %}", # you should provide the file name in one of the template searchpaths
            'useLegacySql': False
                }
        },
        location='EU',
    )
```

Comment: I tried that too, same problem ```jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: test.sql```

Comment: which executor are you using? if you are using Celery or Kubernetes, did you check if the template exists on all the workers in the same path?

Comment: Hi Hussein, thank you for posting your idea above. I posted the actual answer too that I found today, the path to the folder was missing /gcs/ sub folder, not sure why this is required but it works. This solution runs on Cloud Composer + Airflow.